# Create excel file via c# that support filtering merged cells

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to create an excel file via c# in which the cells that contains the same data are merged. This is the easy part, the hard part is to make the excel display **all** the rows of the merged cells with the same value when filtering that value.

For example, for this data:

[image]

I expect this result after filtering the value "bla":

[image]

The result I would normally get after filtering merged cells is only the first row with this value (in this case, the row that contains the value "1").

I have found [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1955-excel-filter-merged-cells.html) solution  which is extremely not elegant and not efficent:

1. Create two copies of the the data, in the first copy merge cells with the same values and in the second copy don't merge cells with the same value.
2. Use the format painter to copy the format of the merged version of the data onto the unmerged version of the data (apparently this way keeps the data of the cells but display them as merged).
3. delete the merged copy of the data.

I guess I can program this solution, but there must be a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easier way.

Comment: @dgorti Are you certain? the "format painter" copy the format, there must be a way to find out what the format should be (without actually creating a copy of the data) and program it.